# Не найдена библиотека "libwvm.so"

Tags: android

В одном из активити используется `SoundPool`. Все работает и воспроизводит, но при запуске появляется сообщение `"Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found"`в логах.

Скажите, что это за библиотека такая и может ли это как-то влиять на воспроизведение коротких аудио на реальных устройствах?

Comment: На каком устройстве вы тестируете свой код? Используете эмулятор?

Comment: Да, на эмуляторе

Comment: Проверьте версии `SDK`. Должно быть так `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"  android:minSdkVersion="14" />`. Возможно, что этой библиотеки просто нет в эмуляторе. Проверьте работоспособность на реальном устройстве.

Answer (score 1):

В форумах народ говорит, что на эмуляторе его и не будет никогда. Это библиотека для DRM, по идее не должна оказывать влияния на воспроизведение аудио, если только на записи не наложены ограничения по DRM лицензиям.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо большое.